# How to increment filename if destination file already exists in python?

Tags: python, copy-paste

I want to copy a file like for example Ubuntu Nautilus file manager does. If destination already exists it creates new filename with larger index. I tried `shutil.copyfile` but it overwrites destination file. How to increment filename if destination file already exists in python?

Comment: That sounds like basic string manipulation on the filename, what did you try?

Comment: @cdarke, I wanted something already in libraries.

Comment: Then this is off-topic because library recommendations are explicitly disallowed on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -1):

```
shutil.copyfile(src, dst, *, follow_symlinks=True)¶
```

Copy the contents (no metadata) of the file named `src` to a file named `dst` and return `dst`. `src` and `dstare` path names given as strings. `dst` must be the complete target file name; look at `shutil.copy()` for a copy that accepts a target directory path. If `src` and `dst` specify the same file, `SameFileError` is raised.

The destination location must be writable; otherwise, an `OSError` exception will be raised. If `dst` already exists, it will be replaced. Special files such as character or block devices and pipes cannot be copied with this function.

If `follow_symlinks` is false and `src` is a symbolic link, a new symbolic link will be created instead of copying the file `src` points to.

Changed in version 3.3: `IOError` used to be raised instead of `OSError`. Added `follow_symlinks` argument. Now returns `dst`.

Changed in version 3.4: Raise `SameFileErrorinstead` of Error. Since the former is a subclass of the latter, this change is backward compatible.

```
exception shutil.SameFileError
```

This exception is raised if source and destination in `copyfile()` are the same file.